# Azure Windows Virtual Desktop - Why Tenant Creation

Tags: windows, virtualization, azure

We are planning on configuring Windows Virtual Desktop within our existing Azure Infrastructure as we want to test an application in that environment and roll out to staff if the performance is satisfactory.

On reading the documentation and watching the videos, one of the stages involves creating a Windows Virtual Desktop tenant. Can we just use our existing Azure tenant or is this a separate thing?

I apologize for this really noob question, but I am being asked. I'm sure there is something online explaining this, but I am unable to find it so please point me to the documentation if so.

Comment: Good question. Have had the same one. Looking forward to the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your WVD host pool will have one or more VMs which will run your applications. These VMs must be an AD domain member. Then you must also install the WVD software on the host(s). **The domain it is a member of must be synchronized with Azure AD.** (if you want to give your end users self service password reset functionality you will also need have at minimum Azure AD Premium P1 for each user you want to have that capability, but that's an aside)

Then, in Azure WVD you will create the host pool, application group, and workspace. You will join the host to the host pool. I have so far only had much success doing a manual spin up of a single VM and then manually adding it to a host pool, but supposedly you should be able to achieve this automatically through the use of sysprep'ed VM images.

**Once you have the pool and application group setup, you will assign *synchronized-from-on-prem* user objects  to the Application Group you want them to access. This is why you need to have the Azure AD Connect setup to sync the users between your 'on-prem' or virtual domain controller and the Azure AD.**

You will also probably need to setup a DNS record for the domain you are using that will allow your users to lookup their feed URL by entering their username/email address associated with the domain.

This is because **the Windows Virtual Desktop web services on the Azure side of things will be handling all the authentication - and that relies on Azure AD - but the management of your host(s) in your host pool is dependent on the virtual or on-prem domain controller for group policy - such as to install applications or configure settings for the remote desktop services session host configuration.**

Given all this background, the answer is **"Yes you can use your existing tenant, if you don't mind your synced directory objects existing in the same Azure AD tenant as your other (cloud-only) directory objects."**

It was for this reason I opted to create a child domain for my WVD hosts and users - to keep them clearly distinct from my other user objects.